# C# ldap creation of local/ domain user throws Access Denied Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ldap, user-accounts, administrator, windows-users

New local/ domain user needs to be created using a Web based application.

I have used System.DirectoryServices and System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespaces to attain it.

So if I run the application using Visual Studio (2012) everything goes smooth (User is getting added to the active directory!).

But if I host the website in IIS and try to do the same operation, it throws an error message saying *Access is Denied*.
I did a research and found out the reason also - It is happening because the APPLICATION POOL Identity is set to an user who has only USER Privileges.

But due to security reasons user with ADMINISTRATIVE Privilege cannot be given as the Application Pool Identity in the application.

So, is there any alternative way to by-pass this Application Pool Identity and allow the user to create local/ domain user successfully.

Waiting for valuable reply/ suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways that this can be achieved.

1. Create a separate app pool with elevated privilege and use move the functionalities that needs elevated access. This can be restricted from usage from outside by having a port binding which is blocked by firewall to be accessed from outside.
2. Create a windows service which runs with as an user with elevated permission. This service can be accesses asynchronously using queues.
3. Move all these elevated permission related functionalities to a new server which has AppPool runs with elevated permission and follow step 1. Do not expose this server to internet traffic to avoid any misuse.